# Rsyncing to a USB drive failing every now and again

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, usb, cygwin

I have been using rsync over ssh (cygwin) for some time now from a Windows 2003 Server to back up files to a Debian box which has a USB hard drive attached.

The files are rsynced directly to the USB hard drive which is mounted as /media/backup on the Debian box.

The backup is run from a scheduled task on the Windows box and the stdout and stderr are output to files which are emailed to me after the backup completes.

Every now and again I see errors in the stderr file like:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/media/backup/[some file name] ": Read-only file system (30)
```

for every file that has changed since the last backup.

When I see this error I unmount the drive and remount. That resolves the problem.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this error occurs? i.e. Why would a USB drive become read-only once every couple of months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem is being made read-only in response to some error in interacting with it.  You should see something come up in `dmesg` and/or `/var/log/messages` (or equivalent) before the `rsync` starts complaining.

Answer (score 0):

What file system is on the USB drive?  If it is NTFS, it might not have been cleanly unmounted.  So the default is generally to mount it read-only until you have run a disk check or until the unclean mount flag is cleared. (Not sure what the flag is actually called).

Comment: The USB drive is formatted ext3.

Comment: Hmmmm...  I would look at dmesg as chaos said.  Maybe something like a journal abort, very well could be a bad drive if you are getting those.  Or maybe the USB cable keeps getting yanked.